# If $g$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ then $f(x)=\int_{a}^{x}g(x)\,{\rm d}x$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity, lebesgue-measure

From the definition this flows naturally up until near the end:

For all $\epsilon>0$, I am looking for a $\delta$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i+1}-x_i|<\delta \implies \sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|<\epsilon$ for all subintervals $(x_{k+1},x_k)$ of $[a,b]$.

Now,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|\int^{x_{i+1}}_{a}g(x)\,{\rm d}x-\int_{a}^{x_i}g(x)\,{\rm d}x\right|\\=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}g(x)\,{\rm d}x\right|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}|g(x)|\,{\rm d}x=\int^{b}_{a}|g(x)|\,{\rm d}x$$

I am not sure how to go on from here. How does this sequence of implications help me find a $\delta$? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\int_a^b |g|\leq \lVert g\rVert_\infty(b-a)$, where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the supremum over all $x\in[a,b]$ of $|g(x)|$. Edit: this is of course assuming that $g$ is bounded.

Comment: Absolute continuity is not defined that way that you stated after "I am looking for".

Comment: First show it for a bounded $g$. This is straightforward. Then show that $\lim_{ M \to \infty} \int_{\{x | g(x) \ge M \}} |g| = 0$ and combine this with the first result.

Comment: @GudsonChou I didn't mention that this $\delta$ exists for all subintervals of $[a,b]$, I didn't want to clot up the space with notation. This is the definition of Royden & Fitzpatrick. What seems wrong with it?

Comment: @copper.hat I understand how you jump from the bounded to the unbounded case by saying the points where the function is unbounded have measure zero and do not affect the result. For the bounded case, do you mean something along the lines of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|<M(b-a)<M\delta => \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M}$?

Comment: @SamM thanks for your comment. Does this look better? $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|<M(b-a)<M\delta => \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M}$

Comment: For all $\epsilon>0$ you need to find a $\delta>0$ such that ... You have it written the wrong way around above.

Comment: Actually I was thinking more along the lines of $\sum_j\int_{x_j}^{x_{j+1}}|g|\leq \lVert g\rVert_\infty\sum_j|x_{j+1}-x_j|<\lVert g\rVert_\infty\delta$.

Comment: @SamM I think we have the same thing, only I meant $M=||g_\infty||$

Comment: @copper.hat You're right, the grammar was awkward I edited it.

Comment: Not quite. You need to look at subintervals.

Comment: @SamM Ah I see what you mean, thx!

Comment: @Craig Now it is right; the previous version wronged the order of the quantifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\int^{x_{i+1}}_{a}g-\int_{a}^{x_i}g|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}g|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}|g|\leq ||g||_\infty\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i+1}-x_i|<||g||_\infty\delta$

So take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{||g||_\infty}$

If $g$ is unbounded, notice that $\lim_{ M \to \infty} \int_{\{x | g(x) \ge M \}} |g| = 0$